# Asp.Net Core 1.0 Error "Failed to make the following project runnable"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm coming to you for help for a problem I have.

I [posted](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3874) the problem in the CLI of dotnet but it's been 10 days+ as of this moment of writing and I have no answer.

I have a project with some dependencies on .NET 4.5 and everything worked properly in RC1 and RC2. Now trying to move to RTM (1.0), I have an error that the project can't be made runnable because the runner can't find a specific DLL. The project compiles fine. Doing `dotnet run` fails

It looks for the DLL in a library that my app (site) uses, specifically `XXX.v15.4, version=15.4.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b881323kd82k.dll` but it does not exist. However, `XXX.v15.4.dll` exists fine.

Copying `XXX.v15.4.dll` into `XXX.v15.4, version=15.4.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b881323kd82k.dll` makes the project run.

The DLL that it's trying to load is a third party library used in a library that the app (site) uses.

Any idea of how I could make the project runnable?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the `project.json`?

Comment: Definitely:

Here it is: [project.json](http://pastebin.com/Q2J9bVhG)

The library that uses the 3rd party is a house library that is referenced in LIB3

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and thought that problem lied in *project.fragment.lock.json* or in *project.json*, but in my case the problem was with incorrect **project.lock.json** files.

It seems like after addition of some new Nuget packages these files need to be recreated.

When i deleted these files, packages have been restored correctly, and the solution successfully built.

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue and it seems like what is happening is some of the dll's are set to read-only post build. SO the next time you build they can not be built.

What I have done to solve the issue is removed all read-only settings from the root folder of my solution.

So for example, if this is your folder structure in windows:
C:\Users**yourname**\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ProjectName

Right-click ProjectName and remove read-only settings recursively.

In my case this has solved the issue and I hope it helps you

Comment: actually no. The problem may lie within the project.fragment.lock.json. Check the github issue for more information

Comment: I just suggested what has solved it on my side for the same error:-) the OP did not post the full error so was tricky to say if my solution to my problem would also work for the OP. I figured I would share it in case since there was no other answers as of yet :)